# resolution not set right on a fresh installation

Tags: 11.10, nvidia, resolution

just intalled ubuntu on the first time! 
There is a problem though with the resolution.

i need the resolution to be 1280X980
however ubuntu only lets it set to 1280X720, plus it says my monitor is unknown.

I have installed the latest nvidia 7800 gtx drivers using additional drivers function.
also no luck with messing with the xrandr function on the terminal.

any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

you can force the adoption of a new resolution using `xrandr`, however i suggest to use the Nvidia control panel for the display management as first step.

all the required steps are described here https://wiki.ubuntu.com/X/Config/Resolution